# MAC OS admin rights vs software removal

Tags: macintosh

not sure whether it is the right place to ask but let's give it a try. I'm looking for a way to prevent users with admin rights on MAC OS to be able to uninstall a certain application as it is easy as this:

```
#sudo /usr/local/McAfee/uninstall DLP
```

Are there any built-in mechanisms ?

I appreciate any hints !

Answer (score 0):

If you are giving a user the ability to use `sudo` to become `root`, you're fighting a lost battle. If they really want to, and they are root, they can do anything.

You could always set up a 'pseudo-`root`' user that is not in `/etc/sudoers`, or create a special group that can write access more places than standard users but not `/Applications`, `/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.. - and then give them the ability to become THAT user with `sudo` by setting up `/etc/sudoers` to allow it. I'd need to know more about your situation to give further recommendations as to where they could write to.

TL;DR not while letting them run anything as `root`.